# Installing xampp form downloaded file?

Tags: linux, xampp

I have downloaded xampp-linux-x64-1.8.3-2-installer.run and now how can I install it in my Linux OS.

Answer (score 1):

I can only speculate that you haven't tried to run the file and you are totally new to Linux and Stackoverflow. The standardish way to run an executable on Linux is this (in a terminal).

Open a terminal

```
cd /Path/to/savedfile
```

Give the file permission to execute. (Google Linux file permissions)

```
chmod 777 xampp-linux-x64-1.8.3-2-installer.run
```

Run the file

```
./xampp-linux-x64-1.8.3-2-installer.run
```

(Totally untested)